# WPF data grid does not scroll horizontally

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid

I can't seem to get the data grid to scroll horizontally.

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Key="BaseDataGrid">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="300"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="150"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="All"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="SizeToHeader"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
    <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="EnableColumnVirtualization" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="AreRowDetailsFrozen" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ClipToBounds" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

Here's the style I am using. All of my datagrids use the autogenerate columns feature. I can't even get the scroll bar itself to even show up.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the XAML surrounding the datagrid itself. Is it placed in a horizontal `StackPanel` or something?

Comment: I think there might be a problem with AreRowDetailsFrozen Property is not applying somehow. What i suggest Just try AreRowDetaisFrozen="False" at your DataGridLevel.  and also Try  to set Property HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to DataGridLevel and If it  is works or not. If it works at your Datagridlevel then there might be problem that your style is not getting applied anyhow. You can also check that Resource File in which this style is defined is loaded during app start.

Comment: I just figured it out actually. Elsewhere I had a style for the scrollviewer that had the horizontal scroll disabled.